# Filename pattern not working in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

i started learning programming a few days ago and i'm working/practicing on a program that copies and pastes several files at the same time, but i'm having trouble when it comes to getting it to work on multiple different extensions

Here's the code

```
namespace practice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string[] getFlies
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string getdirectory
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string[] getextension
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog getfiles = new OpenFileDialog();
                getfiles.Filter = "All Files (.)|.";
                getfiles.FilterIndex = 1;
                getfiles.Multiselect = true;
```

`if (getfiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                getFlies = getfiles.FileNames;


                foreach (string file_name in getFlies)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(file_name);
                    getextension = Path.GetExtension(getFlies);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbb.Description = "Select a folder";

        if (fbb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            getdirectory = fbb.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            File.Copy(getFlies.ToString(), getdirectory);
        }

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
}`

What should I do?

Comment: What do you want to do ? You have to handle each file specifically according its extension ? In this case, in the foreach loop over getFlies, you just have to check it and to behave how you would like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you change the names of your variables to better names. But to keep aligned with your code, I used the names you have selected.
Ok, you can do it like this:

```
// instead of string[]. 
public FileInfo[] getFlies { get; set; } // I suggest to change the name, maybe to Files? 


// in your button1_click method, after the DialogResult is OK
// getFiles in the dialog and getFlies is the array.
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getfiles = new OpenFileDialog();  // again, change the name...maybe for dialog?
    getfiles.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // I fixed it. You missed the '*' .
    // more dialog initialization

    if(Dialog.Result.OK == getfiles.ShowDialog())
    {
        getFlies = getfiles.FileNames.Select( f => new FileInfo(f)).ToArray();
    }
}


// Now, in button3_click
void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var file in getFlies)
    {
        File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(getdirectory, file.Name));
    }
}
```